# QT container class issue

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to create a function that returns a `QStringList` of companies which were originally stored in a `QList<company*> list`. When I try to add items to the `QStringList`, I get the following error:

```
C:\Qt\Qt5.3.0\Tools\QtCreator\bin\test\companylist.cpp:13: error: passing 'const QStringList' as 'this' argument of 'QList<T>& QList<T>::operator+=(const T&) [with T = QString]' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
     m_sortedList += m_companyList.at(i)->toString();
                  ^
```

Any idea what i'm doing wrong?  i've also tried to use `m_sortedList.append()` with no luck...

My code:

```
QStringList CompanyList::getCompanyList() const {
    for (int i = 0; i <= m_companyList.length(); ++i) {
        m_sortedList += m_companyList.at(i)->toString();
    }
    m_sortedList.sort();
    return m_sortedList;
}
```

Comment: May be because "const" in function signature? This const means that internal state of the object will not be changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within `getCompanyList() const`, all members are const. Thus, the type of `m_sortedList` is `const QStringList` and you can't modify it.

There's no reason to have `m_sortedList` as a member, though, since you always overwrite it. Moreover, you never seem to clean it. If you'd call a (non-const) `getCompanyList` more than once, you'd get a list with duplicated entries.

To avoid a premature pessimization when growing a list that will have a known size, you should ensure that it has room for enough elements by calling `reserve`.

What you're looking for is the typical local return value idiom:

```
// C++11
QStringList CompanyList::getCompanyList() const {
  QStringList result;
  result.reserve(m_companyList.size());
  for (auto c : m_companyList) result << c->toString();
  std::sort(result.begin(), result.end());
  return result;
}

// C++03, this is a more declarative style loved by some OSS projects :)
QStringList CompanyList::getCompanyList() const {
  QStringList result;
  result.reserve(m_companyList.size());
  std::transform(c.begin(), c.end(), std::back_inserter(result),
                 std::mem_fn(&company::toString));
  std::sort(result.begin(), result.end());
  return result;
}

// C++98
QStringList CompanyList::getCompanyList() const {
  QStringList result;
  result.reserve(m_companyList.size());
  foreach (company * c, m_companyList) result << c->toString(); // or Q_FOREACH
  std::sort(result.begin(), result.end());
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  i'm not supposed to use the C++ std namespace.  Any idea how I could avoied duplicates otherwise?only QT...

Comment: @user2094257 There's no way to productively use C++ without using the std namespace. Qt uses it plenty itself, even in its headers. You can use the first C++11 variant and replace `std::sort` with `qSort` - that will let you avoid the direct use of std namespace.